# Incomplete hydration when inserting documents following a search with a custom transformer

Tags: php, symfony, foselasticabundle

To speed up search results I'm using a custom query for the elastica_to_model_transformer which retrieves the 20 or so values I need for the listings page, in the form of partial entities.

```
persistence:
    elastica_to_model_transformer:
         query_builder_method: createSearchQueryBuilder
```

However, I have found an unintended side effect. If I retrieve some entities using a search, then update a value in those entities, when the object is converted back to an elasticsearch document for insertion into the index, then only the 20 or so hydrated values are added to the index.

Is there a way to ensure the objects are fully hydrated before updating the index, or can I ignore the custom query when performing certain searches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening because createSearchQueryBuilder returns a partial entity, and it is only this partial entity that it is updated/inserted in the index.

So it looks like the solution is to use

```
$em->refresh($entity);
```

which reloads the entity from the database.

This can be used;

- either the script running the update before any changes are made,
- or in the postUpdate of a doctrine event listener used to update or insert into the index

If you custom query returns partial results for related entities then it's important to add

```
cascade={"refresh"}
```

to the mapping for these relationships.